# "Error near from" in UNION query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm getting an error *"error near FROM"* in SQLite, however I couldn't find any faults in this query. What am I doing wrong?

```
Select
tbltrans2_temp.itemcode,
tbltrans2_temp.itemname,
  Sum(tbltrans2_temp.qty) qty
From 
  tbltrans_temp Inner Join
  tbltrans2_temp On tbltrans2_temp.transID = tbltrans_temp.transid
 where
  tbltrans_temp.saleDate='11/07/2013'
Group By
  tbltrans2_temp.itemcode
  UNION
  Select
  tbltrans2.itemcode,
  tbltrans2.itemname,
  Sum(tbltrans2.qty) qty,
From 
  tbltrans Inner Join
  tbltrans2 On tbltrans2.transid = tbltrans.transid
   where
  tbltrans.saleDate='11/07/2013'
Group By
  tbltrans2.itemcode
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an extra `,` before the second `FROM` remove it:

```
Select
tbltrans2_temp.itemcode,
tbltrans2_temp.itemname,
  Sum(tbltrans2_temp.qty) qty
From 
  tbltrans_temp Inner Join
  tbltrans2_temp On tbltrans2_temp.transID = tbltrans_temp.transid
 where
  tbltrans_temp.saleDate='11/07/2013'
Group By
  tbltrans2_temp.itemcode
  UNION
  Select
  tbltrans2.itemcode,
  tbltrans2.itemname,
  Sum(tbltrans2.qty) qty,    <<<<-------------------  This
From 
  tbltrans Inner Join
  tbltrans2 On tbltrans2.transid = tbltrans.transid
   where
  tbltrans.saleDate='11/07/2013'
Group By
  tbltrans2.itemcode
```

---

### Update

To get the sum of `qty` from both the table, put that query in a subquery and sum it in the outer one, you can also omit the `sum` in the inner query and only do it in the outer one:

```
SELECT 
  itemcode,
  itemname,
  SUM(qty) TotalQty
FROM
(

    Select
    tbltrans2_temp.itemcode,
    tbltrans2_temp.itemname,
      Sum(tbltrans2_temp.qty) qty
    From 
      tbltrans_temp Inner Join
      tbltrans2_temp On tbltrans2_temp.transID = tbltrans_temp.transid
     where
      tbltrans_temp.saleDate='11/07/2013'
    Group By
      tbltrans2_temp.itemcode
      UNION
      Select
      tbltrans2.itemcode,
      tbltrans2.itemname,
      Sum(tbltrans2.qty) qty
    From 
      tbltrans Inner Join
      tbltrans2 On tbltrans2.transid = tbltrans.transid
       where
      tbltrans.saleDate='11/07/2013'
    Group By
      tbltrans2.itemcode
) t
GROUP BY itemcode, itemname;
```

Comment: Thank you and I have another simple question. Now I have a result from 2 querires, How can I get the sum of qty from both the tables? I would be very grateful if you could help me. Thanks

Comment: @SathishD, sorry bro, have to wait 11 minutes